# Norm of an element coprime to a prime algebraic number

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\pi:=1+\sqrt{3}$ be an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$. I have proved that $\pi$ is a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$. Now let $\alpha$ be another element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, such that $\alpha$ is coprime to $\pi$. I'm asked to show that the norm of $\alpha$: $N(\alpha)$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

What I did: $N(\pi)=-2$. If I write $\alpha=x+y\sqrt{3}$, then $N(\alpha)=x^2-3y^2$, and if I reduce modulo $4$, i have $N(\alpha)=1$ or $N(\alpha)=2$ modulo $4$. I have to exclude $N(\alpha)=2\pmod{4}$, I suppose using hypothesis that $\alpha$ is coprime with $\pi$. Can you give me a hint?

$\textbf{Add}$: following Gerry Myerson comment, I consider

$$\displaystyle\frac{x+y\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}\cdot\displaystyle\frac{x-y\sqrt{3}}{1-\sqrt{3}}$$
It is $\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\overline{\alpha}}{\overline{\pi}}=\frac{N(\alpha)}{-2}$. If this is an integer, then $\pi$ divides $\alpha\overline{\alpha}$. Since $\pi$ is prime, $\pi$ divides $\alpha$ or $\pi$ divides $\overline{\alpha}$. Suppose $\pi$ divides $\alpha$, then I have a contradiction because $\alpha$ and $\pi$ are coprime, then it must be $N(\alpha)$ odd, thus $=1\pmod{4}$ as we claimed.

Now suppose $\pi$ divides $\overline{\alpha}$. Then $\overline{\pi}$ divides $\alpha$. Hence I'm reduced to prove that $\overline{\pi}$ is also prime, and is coprime with $\alpha$. But this is easy, since $\overline{\pi}=\pi\cdot(-2+\sqrt{3})$ and $-2+\sqrt{3}$ is a unit, thus $\overline{\pi}$ is associated to $\pi$, thus is itself prime and coprime with $\alpha$

Comment: You should give some consideration to the possibility that $\pi$ divides $\overline\alpha$, but you have the ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $${x+y\sqrt3\over1+\sqrt3}\cdot{x-y\sqrt3\over1-\sqrt3}$$

Comment: I've edited my question